# How to write idiomatic constructor

Tags: go, constructor

I'm confused about the constructors in Go. Most constructors I've seen return a struct, but 'Effective Go' suggests that an interface can be returned in some cases, according to the [rule of 'Generality'](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#generality).

I trust 'Effective Go' to provide good ideas, but this doesn't seem to follow the principle of 'accept interfaces, return structs'. I guess that many types implement an interface and nothing more than that, so in that case it would be common to see constructors which return interfaces.

Another related statement is that interfaces should be defined by the consumer, but 'Generality' means that the interface is defined by the producer.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: "accept interfaces, return structs" isn't rule. It's a guideline. It should be violated sometimes. We always return `error` interfaces, not their concrete types, for example.

Comment: A constructor can return a concretion because its whole job is to return an instance of a particular type. It could still be used by a consumer that expects an interface and stored in an interface variable or passed in an interface parameter.

Comment: Where Effective Go is referring to returning interfaces is in the very specific context of that section - "If a type exists only to implement an interface and will never have exported methods beyond that interface, there is no need to export the type itself. Exporting just the interface makes it clear the value has no interesting behavior beyond what is described in the interface." i.e. this is *specifically for constructors of unexported types*.

Comment: In almost all cases a constructor constructs a non-interface type. The case you seem to think about is rare. IN Go you _start_ with "real" (i.e. non-interface types) and introduce interfaces if needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it has already been mentioned, returning an interface should be considered something exceptional.

Returning errors of type `error` which is an interface is one of those exception.

Returning an interface that represents an unexported type is the other exception. But why would you have an exported interface that describes an unexported struct instead of just having an exported struct?

The reason is simple, that allows you a higher degree of control on how that struct is constructed.

Compare this two pieces of code:

```
type MyType struct {
    MyField string
}

func NewMyType(value string) MyType {
    return MyType{value}
}

func (t MyType) MyMethod() string {
    return t.MyField
}
```

```
type MyType interface {
    MyMethod() string
}

type myType struct {
    MyField string
}

func NewMyType(value string) MyType {
    return myType{value}
}

func (t myType) MyMethod() string {
    return t.MyField
}
```

In the first case I would be able to do: `myVar := MyType{}` while in the second case I won't be able to do so, I am forced to use the provided constructor. The first case also allows to modify the field value after creation which is not allowed in the second case. Making the field unexported will solve the second part but not the first.

This example is obviously trivial, but being able to construct invalid structs may have a horrible impact. By having specific constructors you can ensure that the object is in a valid starting state and you will only need to make sure it always stays in a valid state. If you can't ensure that, you may need to check that it is in a valid state at the start of every method.

For example consider a DB request. It needs a DB connection. If the user is able to create a DB request without a DB connection you will have to check that it is valid in every method. If you enforce him to use a constructor you can check at creation time and done.

Comment: Yes, now that you mention it I realize that error is a good example of when to return an interface.

Comment: Maybe my experience of interfaces is too limited so far. The main reason (if not the only) for why I've defined interfaces is to be able to mock in a convenient way. In those cases the concrete type will not provide any more methods than the interface, so I haven't faced any problems with constructors which return interfaces (except that I'm not happy about the feeling that I probably do it the wrong way).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases constructor functions return concrete types (or pointer to a type).
The situations in which returning interfaces might be a good idea is when calling factory functions or builder functions in which underlying concrete type satisfies that interface.

Consider `error` interface for example, when you call `http.NewRequest` underlying concentrate error type can be of `net.Error`, `net.DNSError` etc. Now try to think how are you going to create an api like this without an `error` interface if function returns concrete type? Only solution to it I can think of is to create a massive error type for `net` package and add fields for extra information, but its most probably much harder to maintain, test that kind of error type and not to mention memory bloat.

Whether you choose to return concrete type or an interface is a design choice, some guidelines exists to give solution to common scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on your preference and how you view things. Coming from OOP background my take is: there is no point in the constructor if you cannot enforce it. Adding the constructor means - you must supply these values when instantiating this item. If your struct is public, it will be misused and instantiated bypassing the constructor. So it makes sense that the constructor returns the public interface and the struct is private (lowercase). If the struct is public, there is no point in the constructor, because you cannot enforce it. Writing code is a dialogue between writer and reader, making a struct public and having a constructor would tell the reader - here you have the constructor, but you also have a public struct and that would mean that constructor usage is arbitrary. If that is the case, go with that setup